# Why using getFreeSpace /getTotalSpace / getUsableSpace gives different output from df -H command

Tags: java

I have an external SSD disk (/dev/sda).

when typing df -h:

```
size used avil use%
587G 383G 175G 69%
```

when typing df -H:

```
size used avil use%
630G 411G 188G 69%
```

When using `getTotalSpace() / (1024*1024)` I'm getting: 600772

When using `getUsableSpace() / (1024*1024)` I'm getting: 178568

When using `getFreeSpace() / (1024*1024)` I'm getting: 209108

If I will try to calculate the usage in parentage I will not get 69%.

What is the bug ?

Comment: If you calculate the percentage yourself from the DF output you don't get 69% either (instead the percentage is the same as in Java, minus a bit of rounding). Go ask on superuser where they may know of the idiosyncrasies of DF

Answer (score 0):

The 69% of `df` is calculated as "used / (used + available)" which is `383 / (383 + 175) = 69%`. It's not calculated as "used / size".

You don't have "used" in Java (it's not the same as "size - available") so you can't make the same calculation.

But you can calculate "available / size" in both cases:

1. 188 / 630 = 30%
2. 209108 / 600772 = 30%

There is no bug. You were comparing different things.

Comment: So how can I calculate this (% of free space) in Java ?

Comment: @Boom I used your numbers in my answer. `209108 / 600772 = 30%` you can see in your question from which java call each of these numbers comes

Answer (score 0):

By default, `ext2/3/4` filesystems reserve `5%` of the space to be useable only by the superuser, `root`.

I think in java `reserve space = free space - usable space`, in you example:

```
|------------- free ----------|
          |-------usable------|----used-----|
|-reserve-|
|xxxxxxxxx|+++++++++++++++++++|=============|
|---------------- total --------------------|


total = 600772
usable = 178568
free = 209108

reserve = free - usable = 209108 - 178568 = 30540

reserve / total = 30540 / 600772 = 0.05 = 5%
```

calculate `df` output by java:

```
size of df == total of java
587G == 600772MB / 1024

used of df == (total - free) of java
383G == (600772 - 209108)MB / 1024

avil of df == usable of java
175G == 178568MB / 1024

use% of df == (total - free) / (total - (free - usable))
69% == (600772 - 209108) / (600772 - (209108 - 178568))
    == 391664 / 570232
    == 0.6868
```